# In mongo how to get the current position of the record in the table with the total records for pagination?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm trying to return create a paginated list. I used graphql to query the data. With my query, I pass the number of records I need (In a variable named `first`) and the ID of the last fetched record (In a varible called `after`). Now I managed to write a query (Note that I used `mongoose`) to fetch the records. Now what I need to do is get the relavant information to perform the pagination like `hasNextPage`, `hasPreviousPage`, `currentPage` and `totalPages`.

To get most of these information I need to get the total number of records in the database. To do that I need to send another db request.

I also need to know the position of the record in the table. No idea how.

Here's the query:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  Company.where('_id')
    .gt(after)
    .limit(first)
    .lean()
    .exec((error, doc) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      }

      resolve({
        edges: doc,
        pageInfo: {
          hasNextPage: '...',
          hasPreviousPage: '...',
          currentPage: '...',
          totalPages: '...'
        }
      });
    }))
```

Any idea how to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this module [mongoose-paginate](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate)

here what i uses, for pagination,

```
var current = req.query.filter.current;
var limit = req.query.filter.limit;
console.log('params.query.filter.current',current);
var skip = Number(limit)*Number(current)-Number(limit);
console.log('skip::',skip);
    Cours.find({'attributes.version.status': true}).skip(skip).limit(limit).sort({_id:'asc'}).exec(function (err, resulta) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('erreur trouverCours');
            res.json({
                protecteds: err
            });
        }
        console.log('cours ::', resulta);
        res.json({
            "data": resulta
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you tried this one [link](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate)

Comment: Thanks. Finally settled with that plugin.

Comment: you are welcome, if my answer is the right one , mark this post as solved